# Jasmine - How to get only specs within current suite?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

I have multiple suites(describes) inside a spec.js file. I would like to implement jasmine-fail-fast and fail only one suite(single describe block) at a time and proceed with the rest in the spec.js file. The available plugin does not support this feature as it tries to get all specs inside the spec.js file at a time.
Is there any workaround for this ? TIA

Comment: What is happending right now could you add your config file spec

Comment: e2e.spec.js:  
`describe('Outer Block', async () => {  
    describe('First Inner Block ', async () => {
           it();
     it();  // Expectation: If this fails, continue to Second Inner Block // Actual: Test stops
     it();              
        });
  describe('Second Inner Block ', async () => {
           it();
     it(); // Expectation: If this fails, continue to Third Inner Block // Actual: Test stops
     it();
        });
  describe('Third Inner Block ', async () => {
           it();
     it();
     it();
        });
  });`

Comment: Conf file:
  
  var failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
  onPrepare() {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
     }

Comment: https://github.com/pmowrer/jasmine-fail-fast/issues/11    This is what I am trying to achieve.